# Find out the size of html page

Tags: java, html, inputstream

I am using the following code to open an input stream from a website url. I wanted to know if there is any way to find out the size of html source before I open the stream.

```
try
{
    URL u = new URL(url);
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(u.openStream());
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String str;
    while ((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        webContent += str;
    }
    reader.close();
}
catch (IOException e)
{
    Console.print(e.getMessage());
}
```

Comment: You could make an HTTP get request to the site and get the size of the data returned

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
URL u = new URL(url);
URLConnection conn = u.openConnection();
int length = conn.getContentLength();
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(conn.getInputStream());
// ...
```

Now `length` will contain the `Content-Length` of the requested resource in bytes.  Note that this will not work for `chunked` transfers, in which case you will need to keep reading until you reach the end of the stream to determine its length.

Comment: Ok. So I used `conn.getContentLength()` and `conn.getContentLengthLong()`. But both of them are returning -1 from me.

Comment: @Xtr33mm That means the web server is sending you something with `Transfer-Encoding: chunked`.  If this is the case, it's not possible to know the size of the stream before reading it all, since the server may be running a script which continually outputs data of a variable size.  So you will have to either read the entire stream into a string and use that, or work around not being able to know the length of the response beforehand.

Comment: Thanks. Actually i was trying to implement a `progressbar` because sometimes it takes about half a minute to get all the data depending on the speed of the internet. So is there anyway i can show a `progressbar` showing how much time is left until all the data is available. It sounds a bit vague but I'm kinda new to this network programming.

Comment: @Xtr33mm There are several approaches to that which would require you to change the format of your web service's responses to track progress, either by adding indicators of progress inline with your response, or providing a separate endpoint for querying the progress of jobs.  This would be a little outside the scope of this question however.